# Wrong position of circle on google maps laravel

Tags: javascript, google-maps, laravel, google-maps-api-3, geometry

im dont a map with a circle on it but when i click on circle infowindow always appear i left top corner. When i replace circle with marker it works fine. Can anyone help me with it ??

```
var map;

var markers = {!! json_encode($maps) !!};

var marks = [];

function load() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.2442266,22.5619917),
        zoom: 13
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        marks[i] = addMarker(markers[i]);
    }
}

function addMarker(marker){

    var id = marker.id;
    var lat = marker.lat;
    var lng = marker.lng;
    var PM10 = marker.PM10;
    var PM25 = marker.PM25;
    var date = marker.date;
    var index;
    var time = marker.time;
    var temp = marker.temp;
    var humidity = marker.humidity;

    var html = "1 2 3";


    var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.lat),parseFloat(marker.lng));

    var mark = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        center : markerLatlng,
        radius :10,
        strokeColor:  '#9a0800',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity:  1,
        fillColor:    '#9a0800',
        fillOpacity:  1,
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(){
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, mark);
    });

    return mark;
}
```

Comment: where do you want the infowindow to appear?  Maybe attach a screenshot demonstrating

Comment: I want infowindow on circle like with marker. Instead
i get something like this http://postimg.org/image/5b1w2d1qp/

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument of `infoWindow.open()` is expected to be a `MVCObject` with a `position`-property, but a `google.maps.Circle` doesn't have a `position`-property.

Possible solution:
Add a `position`-property to the Circle, e.g. via `bindTo`:

```
//add this line after the creation of mark
mark.bindTo('position', mark, 'center');
```